# Find related objects

Tags: c#

I have an array of objects, I want to find all the possible "sets" of combinations of two objects from the array, based on name property and the condiition for a match is same or similar name
For example, given the array:

```
[{Id:1, Name: audi}, {Id:2, Name: BMW}, {Id:3, Name: audi}, {Id:4, Name: benz}, {Id:5, Name: audiq5},{Id:6, Name: BMWx5}]
```

The result I want is the following sets or similar way to represent sets:

```
[{Id:1, Name: audi},{Id:3, Name: audi}]
[{Id:1, Name: audi},{Id:5, Name: audiq5}]
[{Id:3, Name: audi},{Id:5, Name: audiq5}]
[{Id:2, Name: BMW},{Id:6, Name: BMWx5}]
```

are there any algorithms which will help me achieve this

Comment: Do you want this in C# or Javascript?  Pick _one_

Comment: C# is good @maccettura

Comment: Does ordering matter in the pairs? I note that in each case, the id of the first element is smaller than the id of the second element. Do you never make a pair where the id of the first element is larger?

Comment: Do you already have a function that can take two names and determine if they are "similar" or not?  That's the hard part of this question; finding the pairs once you have that function is comparatively easy.  What is this function? If you do not already have that function, then ask a more clear question *specifically* about that function.

Comment: 1) this is not a code writing service. please don't dump your requirements as a whishlist without showing any effort of your own. 2)  "is same or similar " I think you need to be more specific. IS `audi` and `Audi` similar or same? how about `xyaudi` and `audi` ?

Comment: @MongZhu: Though I appreciate the sentiment, and I agree that the poster could show more of their effort and research so far, the question asked is "are there any algorithms to help me?" not "please do my assignment for me".  The problem with the question is that it is vague; let's help the poster crisp it up.

Comment: @EricLippert I agree, that is why I wrote the second part of my comment

Comment: would that definition of similarity suit you ? => the shortest name should be a subset of the longer names. Irrespective whether it is used as a prefix, suffix or infix. comparison should be case insensitive.

Comment: @MongZhu - apologies i am new to the community, still learning what i should ask, what not and How. Thanks for the feed back

Comment: and to answer your question the similarity defination perfectly suits my problem

Comment: @EricLippert order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's represent the data as a class named "TestModel", and include some bonus logic for the "similar" comparison (making some assumption about the vague requirements given), as well as the convenience of human-readable string representation:

```
internal class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSimilar(TestModel other)
    {
        string myName = Name.ToLower();
        string otherName = other.Name.ToLower();

        return myName == otherName
            || myName.Contains(otherName)
            || otherName.Contains(myName);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{{Id: {Id}, Name: {Name}}}";
    }
}
```

Separately, let's have a method somewhere that handles the iteration and construction of "similar" pairs (using tuples for pairs here because they're handy critters):

```
    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<TestModel, TestModel>> FindSimilarModelPairs(TestModel[] models)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < models.Length; ++i)
        {
            TestModel model = models[i];
            // Skip the items already processed in the parent loop, to avoid duplicate pairs - if the sequence of two "similar" pairs is important, then the skip should not be done.
            foreach(TestModel innerModel in models.Skip(i+1).Where(m => model.IsSimilar(m)))
            {
                yield return new Tuple<TestModel, TestModel>(model, innerModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the usage, assuming the context of a simple console app:

```
    TestModel[] list = new[]
    {
        new TestModel{ Id=1, Name="audi"},
        new TestModel{ Id=2, Name="BMW"},
        new TestModel{ Id=3, Name="audi"},
        new TestModel{ Id=4, Name="benz"},
        new TestModel{ Id=5, Name="audiq5"},
        new TestModel{ Id=6, Name="BMWx5"},
    };

    foreach(var match in FindSimilarModelPairs(list))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{match.Item1.ToString()},{match.Item2.ToString()}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter'");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the collection with a nested loop to compare each object with every other

something like:

```
    List <Array> Agrigrate = new List<Array>();
    foreach (foo i in bar)
    {
        foreach(foo j in bar)
        {
            if(i.ID != j.ID && i.Name.Contains(j.Name))
            {
                Agrigrate.Add(new Array[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is just a basic example, but it should be enough to give you an idea for how these things are typically done

Comment: Thanks - @doom87er it is helpful